# cannot import name 'import_string' from 'werkzeug'

Tags: python, flask

Estaba tratando de implementar el guardado de peticiones en cache con `Flask-Cache`, lo he instalado y todo bien, pero al momento de hacer la importación me sale el error de importación.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'import_string' from 'werkzeug' (/home/cc/Desktop/test/alg/envi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py)
```

Esto es debido a que en el módulo `Flask-cache` se está importando `import_string` de esta forma:

```py
from werkzeug import import_string
```

Esto lo he sabido buscando el archivo del módulo instalado en el entorno virtual, claramente la solución es cambiar la forma en que se importa la función, de esta forma:

```py
from werkzeug.utils import import_string
```

Pero claro, esto no lo puedo hacer ya que si modifico manualmente el archivo `__init__.py` de un módulo al momento de desplegar mi app me dará el mismo error ya que todo ocurre de forma automática y no tengo posibilidad de modificar el archivo.

Versión de los módulos:

- `Werkzeug`: `2.0.1`
- `Flask-Cache`: `0.13.1`

¿Cual podría ser la solución en este caso?, acaso debo de instalar otra versión del módulo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Has diagnosticado correctamente el problema. `flask_cache`  intenta hacer un `from werkzeug import_string` y esa sintaxis ha sido marcada como obsoleta (*deprecated*) en `werkzeug`.

Por tanto `flask_cache` contiene un bug que debe ser arreglado por su desarollador, pero parece que este módulo ha dejado de mantenerse (los últimos commits tienen ocho años), por lo que no parece probable que vaya a arreglarlo.

Una solución podría ser hacer un *downgrade* de `werkzeug` (es decir, forzar a instalar una versión más antigua en la que el import que intenta `flask_cahe` aún funcionaba), pero no parece buena idea. Conviene usar siempre las últimas versiones pues se supone que los fallos de seguridad se van corrigiendo y por tanto instalar versiones antiguas puede ser inseguro.

Por suerte, gracias a la flexibilidad de Python y a que todo es dinámico, hay otra solución llamada **monkey patching**. Esto consiste en modificar el comportamiento de una librería "en runtime" (en contraposición a hacerlo modificando el fuente de la librería)

La idea es dotar al módulo `werkzeug` del símbolo `import_string` *antes* de importar `flask_cache`, pero esto sin modificar el fuente de `werkzeug`, sino haciéndolo desde nuestro programa, mediante asignación directa.

Es decir:

```py
from werkzeug.utils import import_string
import werkzeug
werkzeug.import_string = import_string

import flask_cache
```

Como ves, comenzamos por importar el símbolo en la forma correcta (pues `werkzeug` ha movido ese símbolo al submódulo `utils`. Una vez lo tenemos, hacemos `import werkzeug` para crear el espacio de nombres `werkzeug` y por último en ese espacio de nombres creamos un nuevo símbolo `import_string`, y le asignamos el valor del que habíamos importado de `utils`.

Ahora ya podemos importar `flask_cache`. Cuando éste intente `from werkzeug import import_string`, debido a que Python no hace reimports de espacios de nombres ya importados, no se intentará cargar `werkzeug/__init__.py` (que no contiene `import_string`) sino que esa línea simplemente pasará al espacio de nombres de `flask_cache` el símbolo `import_strings` que habíamos añadido al espacio de nombres `werkzeug`.

Hemos parcheado el código de una librería externa sin tocar el código de la librería externa. Esto es lo que se llama *monkey patching*. Ni que decir tiene que esto no está muy bien visto y que hay que limitar su uso a causas justificadas, pero ésta es una de ellas (otros usos típicos pueden ser parchear funciones síncronas bloqueantes para que pasen a ser asíncronas y así hacerlas compatibles con `asyncio`, o hacer *mocking* para testing).